# How to save Tensorflow tokenized text on Mlflow for predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, tokenize, mlflow

Did anyone had saved tf tokenzied data on Mlflow and loaded it for prediction in production code? I know there is a method to write as json or pickle but I have no idea how to send it to Mlflow and load it back from there... Any suggestions how to resolve this issue? Or maybe you found completely differnet solution?

Thank you

Comment: have you found a solution here?

Comment: Yes. Save it with        `with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
             pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`  and them open with `with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)`